# Look for img and id tag, store URL in variable if both are true

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I have been playing around with some Python now and start to get a hang of it.
I have already came up with a project, but I can't work out some things.

The purpose is to look inside a defined tag, such as the img tag or the a tag.
If that's true, it also needs to look for a id tag, always the same one.

If the img take looks like `<img src="/overflow.png" id="true">` I want it to be stored
If the img take looks like `<img src="/overflow.png" id="false">` I don't want it stored.

Hope this is fairly easy to achieve, I just haven't found a solution yet. I have looked up the function for HTMLParser, but it's more gibberish than sense to me. Hope someone knows how to do this, and help me out. Will be much appreciated!

Cheers,
ninjaboi21.

Comment: this website has a good comparison of some of the different parsers out there for python

http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/

Comment: @Marty That's just a speed and memory comparison, it doesn't compare features or ease of use. It doesn't seem relevant to his question.

Comment: they all basically do the same thing, and all are capable of doing what his question is asking. and also that's why my response was a comment not an answer ..

Comment: @ninjaboi I notice you haven't accepted any answer to most of your questions. Please remember to accept an answer if one has helped you.

Comment: Oh, didn't even realize that, thought an up vote was enough. I have marked the best answer with a tick now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People generally use BeautifulSoup, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/, to do this sort of thing.

After installing:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# if the file is on your computer use this
#file = open('/path/to/the/file')
# and if the file is on the internet use this
#import urllib
#file = urllib.urlopen('http://www.the.com/path/to/the/file')
html = file.read()
file.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
trueimages = [image for image in soup.findAll('img') if image['id'].lower() == 'true']
```

Edit: added how to get the file into the string.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but have an error - NameError: "name 'html' is not defined" - how do I fix that?

Comment: `html` is the name I used for the string where you have the html document stored. So you need to open the file with `file = open('/path/to/the/file')` if it's on your computer, or `file = urllib.urlopen('http://www.the.com/path/to/the/file')` if it's on the internet, then read it into a string with `html = file.read()`.